# Unable to add bgimage in CSS

Tags: css, html

The below is my piece of code, I am not able to add background-image in my web page, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q813G.jpg)

Comment: Post the code as text, and don't use external image link for question relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create folder called 'images' near your class_id.html file are located and Copy "Aravind_Signature.jpg" image to the newly created image folder 
and then change the css *background-image* property as below

```
background-image:url("images/Aravind_Signature.jpg");
```

Note : its bad approach for referring image files path starting from drive names like "c:\". Because when you share your code you need change image path always.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong, you just need to look at referring to path this way...

either use '/' or '\' so that you will get the right path.